# Pandas:XLDR error while reading an xls file from a url

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, pyexcel

i am getting an error while reading an xls file the error is as stated below

```
**XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\x08jstanle'**
```

i tried out various solution but ended up with no luck  other tools like xlrd,pyexcel but still facing this error.hope someone out there has a solution to this issue.Also i tried to read it as raw file using pythons io library but the issue is there are multiple sheets in file the sequence need to be maintained

Thanks in Advance
Your Good Health

Comment: can you show the code that you have written to take from the url?

Comment: well the code is complicated i am using pandas.read_excel(link)

Comment: if you open it from a excel viewer the notebook is downloaded as you wished?

Comment: i even tried it by downloading a local file but still its giving error

Comment: sorry for the confusion i mean have you open that file from a excel viewer like MS Excel or Open Office? its probably password encrypted

Comment: yeah i opened it there are other links that contain xlsx files and i am able to read them only xls files are giving error

Comment: then what is the version of xlrd that you are using of?

Comment: its the latest version

Comment: can you re save the workbook in xlsx format and see?

Comment: i am reading from a  remote server the issue is that there are multiple files and i need some automated solution manually its impossible to  save each file as xlsx and unfortunately i am not able to read it using any library

Comment: i mean just for a test run can you test it for one and then if this is the case you are having it can be automated.

Comment: also it seems that file is corrupt because on opening manually it gives away a warning

Comment: state the error please?

Comment: there is some issue with the format its not in format as specified by extension

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible reasons for this:

1).The file that you've getting from the source url is not as the
   same file format as the file extension says

2).XLS files are encrypted if you explicitly apply a workbook
    password but also if you password protect some of the worksheet
    elements. As such it is possible to have an encrypted XLS file even
    if you don't need a password to open it.

if you have the problem number one the you have a solution open the workbook and save it as the supported format.

```
file1 = io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
data = file1.readlines()
# Creating a workbook object
xldoc = Workbook()
# Adding a sheet to the workbook object
sheet = xldoc.add_sheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
# Iterating and saving the data to sheet
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    # Two things are done here
    # Removeing the '\n' which comes while reading the file using io.open
    # Getting the values after splitting using '\t'
    for j, val in enumerate(row.replace('\n', '').split('\t')):
        sheet.write(i, j, val)

# Saving the file as an excel file
xldoc.save('myexcel.xls')
```

the file you've downloaded it would be html also.use below code snippet to verify for a one file.

```
import pandas as pd
df_list = pd.read_html('filename.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list[0])
```

Comment: thanks man i tried the second one but excel file contains multiple sheets and i am not able to track them

Comment: test for one excel file and see i think you are downloading different formatted file. use the second method and verify.